# Dimension invariance

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, reference-request, geometric-measure-theory

Where can I find the Theorem of invariance of the dimension with diffeomorphisms? And about Between Homeomorphism?

I also want to know about the Hausdorff dimension invariance what is deeper!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by invariance of dimension?

Comment: Well we have diffeomorphism between two open sets of $R^n$ and $R^m$ then we must have $n=m$. The same for homeomorphism! About Hausdorff dimension it is more subtle!

Comment: Do you want proof? Or what?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Well, I want a reference for the result with a proof would be nice!

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is a diffeomorphism between two open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$, respectively. Then $df_x: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ is a linear isomorphism between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$, hence $m=n$.  If $f$ is only assumed to be a homeomorphism  the result is more subtle and you can find the proof in any algebraic topology book (e.g. Hatcher, Rotman, ...)

Comment: About the Hausdorff measures dimensions?

Comment: @chessmath  For the Hausdorff dimensions you can find the result in Folland (Real Analysis).